# Which theory does this reentry heating rate equation come from?

Tags: reentry, thermal, heat-shield, heat, thermodynamics

The paper by [Wang et al. at Scitech 2018](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2018-1871) uses the following constraint on the rocket heating rate (equation (3) in the paper):

### $$k_Q \sqrt{\rho} V^{3.15} \le \dot{Q}_{max}$$

([screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMjML.png))

I am wondering what is the original source for this heating rate model? Where does this equation originate from?

Comment: I've formatted your equation using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619), can you double check it? Thanks!

Comment: Heating rate is proportional roughly to the cube of velocity.  It’s an order of magnitude estimation based on the fact that heating comes from a combination of stagnation enthalpy (proportional to $v^2$ at high velocities) and convective heat transfer (proportional to $v^1$).  I think the 3.15 power is a fudge factor for other uncertainties.

Comment: @Paul  that's a great explanation, but can you give a reference source (even a textbook)?

Comment: It’s a standard estimate for high speed air flow.  Most text books on compressible supersonic/hypersonic flow usually mention this as a back of the envelope estimate of heating.  One standard textbook that briefly mentions this estimate is J D Anderson’s Intro to Aerodynamics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Detra-Kemp-Riddell model for stagnation heating.

Detra, R. W.; Kemp, N. H.; and Riddell, F. R.: Addendum to "Heat Transfer to Satellite Vehicles Re-entering the Atmosphere." Jet Propulsion, vol. 27, no. 12, Dec. 1957, pp. 1256-1257. [published online](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/8.12603)

Equation 32 (page 20) and Ref 6 in NASA TM X-2058 [A General Transient Heat-Transfer Computer Program for Thermally Thick Walls](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19700027773.pdf) L. Bernard Garrett and Joan I. Pitts, 1970